# setTimeout function to fade formOut form and fadeIn success message and than fadeOut success message and fadeIn form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am having a small problem with my contact form.  currently the form submits and displays a confirmation message and I want to change this so the form fades out and the success message fades in and after about 4 seconds the success message fades out and the form fades back in.

My code for the form is

```html
<div class="contacts-form">

 <form action="" method="post" id="contact">
  
 <p class="confirm dn">Thank you, your message has been sent successfully <br/> We will reply back to you within 24hrs.</p>
 <p class="error dn">Please correct the errors and re-submit the form!</p>
 
 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="tbl_contact">
  <tr>
   <th class="name"><label for="name"></label></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="last-item" placeholder="Full Name" /><span class="require">*</span>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th class="email"><label for="email"></label></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="last-item" placeholder="Email" /><span class="require">*</span>
   </td>
  </tr> 
        <tr>
   <th class="web"><label for="web"></label></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input type="text" name="web" id="web" class="fld" value="" placeholder="Web Site" />
   </td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
   <th class="subj"><label for="subj"></label></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input type="text" name="subj" id="subj" class="fld" class="last-item" placeholder="Subject"/><span class="require">*</span>
   </td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
    <th class="message"><label for="message"></label></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
                 <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Your Message..."></textarea><span class="require">*</span>
                </td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="no-bottom-margin" />
     <div id="loader" class="dn"><img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Please wait" />&nbsp;Please Wait...</div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 
</form>
<p>&nbsp</p>

</div>
```

And my JS code is as below -

```js
$(function() {

 if ($("#contact").length > 0) {
 
  $("#contact").submit(function() {
  
   $('#button').hide();
   $('#loader').show();
   $("#contact .warn").remove();
   
   var fields = $(this).serializeArray();
   
   $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : '../inc/contact.php',
    data : fields,
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function(data) {
    
     $('#button').show();
     $('#loader').hide();
     
     if (data.error) {
      
      $('.error').fadeIn(300);
      
      jQuery.each(data.fields, function(k, v) {
       $('.' + k).append('<span class="warn">' + v + '</span>');
       $('.warn').fadeIn(500);
      });
      
     
     });
     
     $('.error').fadeOut(3000);
     
     
     });
      
     } else {
      
      $('.error').hide();

                                                $(".confirm").html(data.message).fadeIn(500);
      $('.confirm').fadeOut(8000);
      /*$('.confirm').fadeIn(300, function() {
       var d = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.confirm').fadeOut(400);
       }, 2000);
      }); */

      
      $('#name, #email, #web, #subj, #message').val('');
      
     }
     
    }
    
   });
   
   return false;
   
  });
 }

});
```

Anyone advise how I can add the setTimeout function to this code to fadeOut the form and fadeIn the success message and than fadeOut the success message and fadeIn the form again.

Thank for the help.